# In a file some variable names are written that needs to be replaced with newly generated random values using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am wanting to replace variables in a CSV file with a randomly generated variable for each of the variables.

For instance, changing 'not available' to either 'male' or 'female'

Sample:

```
Number    Sex
0         Female
1         Male
2         Not Available
3         Male
4         Not Available
```

after random change:

```
Number    Sex
0         Female
1         Male
2         Female
3         Male
4         Male
```

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def RandomSex():
    return random.choice(['Male','Female'])


df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv')
df2 = df.loc[: , 'Sex']
print(df2)
df.loc[(df.Sex == 'Not Available'),'Gender'] = RandomSex()
print(df2)
```

But this is changing all of the 'Not Available' to either all 'Male' or all 'Female'

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the number of `"Not Available"`s and then look for [choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with `random.choices`  from your list instead of choosing only one (which `random.choice` does):

```
not_availables = df.Sex.eq("Not Available")
num_not_availables = not_availables.sum()

choice_list = ["Male", "Female"]
new_values = random.choices(choice_list, k=num_not_availables)

df.loc[not_availables, "Sex"] = new_values
```

to get (for example)

```
Number  Sex
0       Female
1       Male
2       Male
3       Male
4       Female
```